# Set orientation of signaturepad to landscape mode always in IOS MVVMCROSS application

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross, signaturepad

I have implemented signaturepad for my ios application. (Its not a native application. I am developing using MVVMCROSS platform. I wish to set the orientation of this signature pad in landscape view always. I am unable to find any parameters for the  signaturepad frame.

```
 var signature = new SignaturePadView(View.Frame);
 View.AddSubview(signature);
 signature.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 135, 320, 130);
 //signature.Frame = new RectangleF(0, 135, this.View.Frame.Width, 140);
 signature.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray;
```

I am not able to make sure that it always  opens in landscape view and adjusts to the width of the screen. Would be glad if you anyone could help

Comment: Check this out,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554036/mvvmcross-how-to-force-a-specific-orientation-on-mvxviewcontroller-in-ios-7-on

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code to your ViewController of SignaturePadView

```
public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.AllButUpsideDown;
    }
```

It overrides orientation methods