# how to disable screen rotation in MvxViewController in IOS App

Tags: c#, ios, mvvmcross, shouldautorotate

I want to disable 1 MvxViewController from rotating using IOS > 6. Simple thing, right?
Not working for me.
So i generated simple MvvmCross IOS project and added 3 overrides. Not even breaking there. What am I missing?

Thank you
Mark

```
public class FirstView : MvxViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        View = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.White };
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        // ios7 layout
        if (RespondsToSelector(new Selector("edgesForExtendedLayout")))
        {
           EdgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None;
        }

        var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(10, 10, 300, 40));
        Add(label);
        var textField = new UITextField(new CGRect(10, 50, 300, 40));
        Add(textField);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<FirstView, App3.ViewModels.FirstViewModel>();
        set.Bind(label).To(vm => vm.Hello);
        set.Bind(textField).To(vm => vm.Hello);
        set.Apply();
    }


    public override bool ShouldAutorotate()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public override UIInterfaceOrientationMask GetSupportedInterfaceOrientations()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait ;
    }
    public override UIInterfaceOrientation PreferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation()
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So what's your current output compared to expected output? Please tell us your specific problem.

Comment: It might be worth reading up about how to manage ios screen rotation - e.g. http://koreyhinton.com/blog/lock-screen-rotation-in-ios8.html - if your view is presented inside e.g. a navigation controller - then make sure that the navigation controller is assisting with your rotation plans.

Comment: Did you have a look at this article?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19554036/mvvmcross-how-to-force-a-specific-orientation-on-mvxviewcontroller-in-ios-7-on